# .dropna doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I am seeing some odd behaviour when using `.dropna` on a `dataframe` named `lcd` within IPython notebook:

```
In[1]
print "Before %f" % lcd.last_pymnt_date.isnull().sum()
lcd.last_pymnt_date.dropna(inplace=True)
print "After %f" % lcd.last_pymnt_date.isnull().sum()

Out[1]
Before  84.0000
After   0.0

In[2]
print lcd.last_pymnt_date.isnull().sum()

Out[2]
84.0000
```

Comment: Is `lcd` a DataFrame?  You can't dropna from a single column, because it would change the size of the DataFrame.  Can you show a complete example include dummy data?

Comment: The lcd.last_pymnt_date.isnull().sum() statements are exactly the same and there are no operations on lcd in between the 'After' statement and the one on In[2], so I don't see how you would get different values.

Comment: @ BrenBarn....what do you mean by complete example?   I now understand that .dropna will change the size of the DF.   How do I drop an entire row from from the DataFrame when encountering .nan in this feature?

Comment: @Alexander - understood, which is why I'm stumped..

Comment: Which version of Pandas are you using.  Does this problem also occur on the latest version (0.16.1)?

Comment: Believe its iPy version 3.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve